# Making bulma site like the same in mobile as desktop

Tags: web, mobile, bulma, responsiveness

I am creating a website using the bulma.io framework. One of the advantages of Bulma is that it's very responsive to changing the size of your screen, which makes it great for mobile.

However, for me, I don't want this functionality. I want the site on mobile to look exactly the same as on desktop, simply zoomed it so the viewer can still see what they want with the right layout.

I'm not at all a CSS/HTML/JS expert and I'm very new to web design, but I was wondering if anyone has a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

> By default, columns are only activated from tablet onwards. This means
>   columns are stacked on top of each other on mobile.  If you want
>   columns to work on mobile too, just add the is-mobile modifier on the
>   columns container.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="columns is-mobile">
  <div class="column">1</div>
  <div class="column">2</div>
  <div class="column">3</div>
  <div class="column">4</div>
</div>
```

https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/responsiveness/

Comment: I figured that out earlier and tried it out. The problem is, however, that it still tries to condense it all to my mobile screen. This leads to the columns being so narrow that the text and images also don't fit properly anymore. Example: https://i.imgur.com/ot60dUh.jpg is a screenshot on mobile. The website can be viewed on PC here: https://downloads.empirewar.org/tim/index.html

Comment: The text and images must be responsive, too.

Comment: How would I do that? Do I need to add is-mobile to all text and images too?

Comment: `is-mobile` means that the width of the columns change dynamically. If you don't set it, the columns will stack and take the whole width when the screen width is `<= 768px`. If you want to make an image responsive with Bulma, you do something like `<figure class="image is-square"><img src="..." width="60" height="60"></figure>` https://bulma.io/documentation/elements/image/#responsive-images-with-ratios . Just use the aspect ratios that Bulma provides.

Comment: "Flexible" font sizes with Bulma: https://bulma.io/documentation/modifiers/typography-helpers/ . For example, you could add `is-size-7-mobile` to a heading. But that doesn't exactly fit.

Without using Bulma, you could do something like https://codepen.io/aknip/pen/GpGevp or use a library, for example `FitText` https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/lDBvc. The problem is that you cannot see the type any more on small screens.